# migration from rails 3.1 to 3.2 with plugins and fix the deprecation warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, rails-upgrade

I am working in a project with Ruby version 1.9.3 and Rails Version 3.1.12. Planning to Migrate the rails Version  to 3.2.The issue encountered is with plugins; we have 6 plugins namely,

- autocomplete
- filter
- has_details
- in_place_editing
- restful-authentication
- role_requirement

I was able to upgrade the Gemfile in Dev, But the show stopper found is the plugins, using this doc,
 http://matt.coneybeare.me/how-to-convert-simple-rails-23-style-plugins/

I was able to convert the autocomplete to include in the lib/. The main issue is with the others. Rest of them contains some files called

> install.rb, Rakefile, templates folders.

is there any way to remove these deprecation warnings, So far, we do not have much test coverage only a low amount.Any Help is appreciated. TIA.

> DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in
>   vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails
>   4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See
>   the release notes for more on this:
>   http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released.
>   (called from  at
>   /home/rmed176lt/ror/revremit/config/environment.rb:6)

If anybody wants to view the plugin code, Please visit
https://github.com/anoobbava/plugins

Comment: You don't have to put them in lib . You can just copy them to a folder 'engines' and then in Gemfile You can load them. like this : gem 'autocomplete', path: 'engines/autocomplete'. No need to modify the gems .

Comment: @RadaBogdan, Could not find gem 'auto_complete (>= 0) ruby' in source at .Source does not contain any versions of 'auto_complete (>= 0) ruby'

Comment: What do You mean? Maybe If You could explain in words what You did i could help. instead of just copy-pasting an error without giving any details . So could You please give me more details?

Comment: Sorry,  i have moved the plugin and created a folder called engines inside project root folder. Then added this line  gem 'autocomplete', path: 'engines/autocomplete. then done the bundle install. now i got the above error.

Comment: Well it seems You have made a mistake somewhere...dont know where...because You didn't share with me the backtrace....you wrote somewhere 'auto_complete' instead of 'autocomplete' . Please check your code again. Probably you gave the wrong name either in gemspec or Gemfile.